# how to rewrite URL using .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having problem in rewriting a url using .htaccess file.  I am not aware of regex. I have red so many blogs and used online rewrite rule generator to generate url and pasted in .htaccess file. But no one is worked. I have enabled mod_rewrite module in httpd.conf file in apache server.

I want to rewrite a below url.

I have developed project in OS - Win7 with Apache server.

```
http://localhost:81/quora/tamilnanban/innerpage.php?url=why-you-should-avoid-watching-porn-on-android-smartphones
```

to

```
http://localhost:81/quora/tamilnanban/why-you-should-avoid-watching-porn-on-android-smartphones
```

my current .htaccess file contains below codes:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
#RewriteRule ^url/([^/]*)\.html$ :81/quora/tamilnanban/innerpage.php?url=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^/quora/tamilnanban/([^/]*)\.html$ /quora/tamilnanban/innerpage.php?url=$1 [L]
```

This above rule also not working. Kindly help me to achieve url rewriting using .htaccess file. Also if i am doing any mistakes in the above steps, please correct me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert `/quora/tamilnanban/innerpage\.php\?url=foobar"` to `/quora/tamilnanban/foobar` you can use the following rules in `/quora/tamilnanban/.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine on

#1)Redirect "/quora/tamilnanban/innerpage\.php\?url=foobar" to "/quora/tamilnanban/foobar"#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /quora/tamilnanban/innerpage\.php\?url=(.+)\sHTTP  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /quora/tamilnanban/%1? [L,R]
#2)The rule bellow will internally map "/quora/tamilnanban/foobar"" to "/quora/tamilnanban/innerpage\.php?url=foobar"#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ /quora/tamilnanban/innerpage\.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I have used your code in .htaccess file. Now url is displayed in browser as expected. But the page is redirected to localhost page instead of expected corresponding page. Kindly help me, if anything need to be changed in your code. Thanks.

Comment: @Janaki where exactly should the page redirect to?

Comment: I will get query string value (url param value) in innnerpage.php and display the page content based on the url value.

Comment: @Janaki the rule already redirects to /innerpage. where is the htaccess located?

Comment: inside of /tamilnanban folder.

Comment: Now your code is working fine. Thank u very much. I am not aware of regex. Can u please explain the above code. So than i can get little bit knowledge and it will help me in future.

Comment: @Janaki i have explained  the code in #comments. You can read more about url-rewriting and the regex on official documentation of apache


http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thanks @starkeen. Also i need another one help in this url rewriting. How can I rewrite the below url. `http://localhost:81/quora/tamilnanban/innerpage.php?id=1& url=why-you-should-avoid-watching-porn-on-android-smartphones`  to `http://localhost:81/quora/tamilnanban/1/why-you-should-avoid-watching-porn-on-android-smartphones`